# tkinter Classes are being annoying

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame, tkinter-entry

I've been trying to work through the very basics of tkinter just to get to the point at which I can print the content of a number of entry fields to the console before I try to learn anything else. I had it to the point at which it looked the way I wanted, but didn't have the functionality I needed. It was suggested that I create a class and do it that way, at which point my GUI is an empty frame without any of the widgets I had added. Does anyone know why this may be?

```
from tkinter import *

class Information:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.titleLabel = Label(frame, text='Welcome to the Redaction Solutions editor!\nPlease enter the requested filepaths below.')
        self.titleLabel.pack(side=TOP)

        self.originalLabel = Label(frame, text='File to be edited')
        self.originalLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.originalEntry = Entry(frame)
        self.originalEntry.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.namesLabel = Label(frame, text='Items to be removed')
        self.namesLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.namesEntry = Entry(frame)
        self.namesEntry.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.destinationLabel = Label(frame, text='Edited file')
        self.destinationLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.destinationEntry = Entry(frame)
        self.destinationEntry.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.invoiceLabel = Label(frame, text='Invoice data')
        self.invoiceLabel.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.invoiceEntry = Entry(frame)
        self.invoiceEntry.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.demoButton = Button(frame, text="Test", command=self.test)
        self.demoButton.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.resetButton = Button(frame, text="Reset Fields", bg="red", fg="black", command=self.reset)
        self.resetButton.pack(side=RIGHT)

    def test(self):
        print(self.originalEntry.get())
        print(self.namesEntry.get())
        print(self.destinationEntry.get())
        print(self.invoiceEntry.get())

    def reset(self):
        self.originalEntry.delete(0, END)
        self.namesEntry.delete(0, END)
        self.destinationEntry.delete(0, END)
        self.invoiceEntry.delete(0, END)

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("RS")
b = Information
root.iconbitmap(r'c:\Users\pbrow\Documents\logoicon.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

I'm also 99% sure this is roughly the worst way to have written this program... and I'm okay with that. I just want it to function properly, I have resigned myself to worrying about optimising at a (much) later date

Answer (score 2):

Never mind my previous attempt at an answer.  The issue is:

```
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("RS")
b = Information
root.iconbitmap(r'c:\Users\pbrow\Documents\logoicon.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

You should be doing:

```
b = Information(root)
```

to actually create the Information object.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it needs to be `b = Information(root)`, since the `__init__` method expects one argument (beyond `self`).

Comment: @Blckknght you're correct, I updated the answer.  Thanks!